# ElasticSearch (NEST) Search by Number

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I apologize in advance if this is a basic question - I am extremely new to ElasticSearch and it's a lot to take in.

For now, I'm trying to implement a basic keyword search that searches all indexed columns and I get some weird results with a specific field, `Year`. I have a certain number of documents I know should come back from the results and if I do a search for "2014", all of them come back successfully. If I do a search for just "14", nothing comes back at all, and if I add a wildcard (e.g. `*14`), then I get a single result back, because it didn't use the `Year` in the search and instead pulled it from the `Description` field.

I'm 100% positive this is something I'm doing wrong with the query structure, so any tips? As an aside, if anyone can provide suggested places to learn more about Elastic with NEST, it'd be extremely helpful. Their documentation is lacking a bit, where you have to understand how to use Elastic already for most of it to make sense and since I don't, I'm left stumbling through.

Here is the structure of `ElasticListing`:

```
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    public string ActiveTags { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }
```

The search structure I'm using with NEST is this, where `keyword` would be "2014" (no quotes):

```
var response = this.ElasticClient.Search<ElasticListing>(s => s
            .AllTypes()
            .Query(query => query
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Must(must => must
                        .QueryString(qs => qs.Query(keyword))
                    )
                )                   
            )
            .Size(pageSize)
            .Explain()              
        );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking to perform is a `term` query on the `Year` field in Elasticsearch

```
var response = client.Search<ElasticListing>(s => s
    .AllTypes()
    .Query(query => query
        .Term(f => f.Year, 2014)
    )
    .Size(pageSize)
    .Explain()
);
```

Take a look at the [writing queries section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html) of the documentation.

In order to perform a wildcard query on the `Year` field, it needs to be indexed as a [`keyword` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) (`keyword` does not analyze the input at index time, which is probably what we want for a numerical value being indexed as a "string").

By default, NEST will serialize the `Year` field as a number within JSON and Elasticsearch will infer the mapping for this as a numeric data type. Even with NEST's [automapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html), NEST will infer an `integer` data type mapping for `Year`, to match the CLR type `Int32` of the property. So, we need to override this inferred mapping to ensure `Year` is indexed as a `keyword` data type.

Here's a complete example

```
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "listings"; 
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    // Make this example re-runnable. You likely want to remove this :)
    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);     

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<ElasticListing>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    // override the default inferred mapping for Year
                    .Keyword(k => k
                        .Name(n => n.Year) 
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    client.IndexMany(new [] {
        new ElasticListing { Id = 1, Year = 2012 },
        new ElasticListing { Id = 2, Year = 2013 },
        new ElasticListing { Id = 3, Year = 2014 },
        new ElasticListing { Id = 4, Year = 1014 },      
    });

    client.Refresh(defaultIndex);

    var pageSize = 10;

    // returns only document with Id = 3
    var response = client.Search<ElasticListing>(s => s
        .AllTypes()
        .Query(query => query
            .Term(f => f.Year, 2014)
        )
        .Size(pageSize)
        .Explain()
    );

    // returns documents with Ids = 3 and 4
    response = client.Search<ElasticListing>(s => s
        .AllTypes()
        .Query(query => query
            .Wildcard(f => f.Year, "*14", rewrite:(MultiTermQueryRewrite)null)
        )
        .Size(pageSize)
        .Explain()
    );
}

public class ElasticListing
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string ActiveTags { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Amazing - thank you! It looks like searching will require wildcards, but otherwise that worked exactly as I needed it to.

Comment: No worries @RubyHaus :) Just be careful about being overzealous with wildcard and regex queries; for some queries, consider them to be analogous to performing a table scan in a relational database. If wishing to perform these kinds of queries frequently on the `Year` field, consider creating it as a `text` datatype with suitable analysis for the kinds of queries you expect to perform.